# How to get IP address from aiohttp response

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am have been trying to look into responses from aiohttp requests and have not found a way to get the ipaddress of the specified host:

```
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    async with session.get(f'http://{host}') as response:
        print(response.__dir__())
        #Wanting to get ipaddress of response right here
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume your host is represented by a url (otherwise you already have the IP)

So what you need to do is get an ip address by url.
You can do this by:

```
import socket
print socket.gethostbyname('your hosto name')
```

your host name is probably 'http://{host}'

Comment: I was looking to see if i could get it from the response object to limit more requests as aiohttp requests has to resolve the domain anyways and im trying to keep speed as this is asynchronous. I found something that works temporarily but not really what im looking for:  

```resolve = await response.connection._connector._resolve_host(host, 0)
host_ips = [resolution['host'] for resolution in resolve]```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    async with session.get(f'http://{host}') as response:
        print(response.connection.transport.get_extra_info('peername'))
```

[source](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/642)