# Retrieve IP address from Python aiohttp response

Tags: python-3.x, aiohttp

I am trying to retrieve the ip address from the a aiohttp response.
This is an asynchronous application so I'm trying to avoid performing an additional request to resolve the ip.

```
async with client_session.request(http_method, url, timeout=timeout_secs) as response:
    # print ip-adddress here
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get IP address from aiohttp response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60142383/how-to-get-ip-address-from-aiohttp-response)

Comment: That could work though not really what I was looking for.
An equivalent aiohttp version of this is what I was looking for :  

resp = requests.get('https://some_url.com', stream=True)
resp.raw._connection.sock.getsockname()